# How to load a4j:outputPanel from DropDown(<h:selectOneMenu>) using ajax call in Richfaces?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

This is related to richfaces 4.0

I have two dropdown in my webpage. On selecting item on first DropDown, Second DropDown(Invisible previously) is easily rendered on webpage .

On selecting the item in second drop down, I want to render a separate panel(Not able to do this).

Problem is that I can render second DropDown on webpage successfully after selecting item from first dropdown, but no panel is rendered when I am selecting second dropDown item .

My code is as follows :

```html
 <rich:panel header="Select Operation" style="margin-top: 20px;  height: 110px">
            <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                <h:form>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="4">
                        <h:outputLabel value="Operation: " style="font-size: small; font-weight: 900"/>
                        <h:selectOneMenu style="margin-left: 10px; width: 150px" value="#{adminBean.currentType}">                                
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="" />
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Add New User" />
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Manage Balance" />
                            <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="Manage Account" />
                            <a4j:ajax event="valueChange" render="second" execute="@this" />                                
                        </h:selectOneMenu>

                        <h:form>
                            <a4j:outputPanel id="second" layout="block">
                                <h:outputLabel value="Type : " style="margin-left: 130px; font-size: small; font-weight: bold;" rendered="#{not empty adminBean.currentType}"/>
                                <h:selectOneMenu style="margin-left: 10px; width: 150px" value="#{adminBean.currentItem}" rendered="#{not empty adminBean.currentType}">
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Participant" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Administrator" />
                                    <a4j:ajax event="valueChange"  render="rep"  execute="@this" />   
                                </h:selectOneMenu>

                            </a4j:outputPanel>                            
                        </h:form>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </h:form>

            </h:panelGrid>

        </rich:panel>                

        <rich:panel style="margin-top: 20px; min-height: 500px">

            <a4j:outputPanel id="rep">

                <rich:panel rendered="#{not empty adminBean.currentItem}" header="Add Customer">

                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <a4j:commandButton value="Add New" style="width: 70px"></a4j:commandButton>
                        <a4j:commandButton value="Delete" style="margin-left: 10px; width: 70px"></a4j:commandButton>
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    </rich:panel>
                   </a4j:outputPanel>
            </rich:panel>
```

As explained above I want id="rep" to be rendered when selecting item from second  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

- You have nested forms which result in invalid HTML.
- You should give ID's to your components.

This should be the code fixed (note that I removed all the unnecessary attributes in order to make the page work as styles):

```html
<rich:panel id="pnlContainer">
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" id="grdSingleCol">
        <h:form id="frmData">
            <h:panelGrid columns="4" id="grdData">
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{adminBean.currentType}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="" />
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Add New User" />
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Manage Balance" />
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="Manage Account" />
                    <a4j:ajax render="second" execute="@this" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>

                <a4j:outputPanel id="second" layout="block">
                    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{adminBean.currentItem}">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Participant" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Administrator" />
                        <!-- check how to render components outside the form -->
                        <a4j:ajax render=":pnlRepContainer:rep" execute="@this" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </a4j:outputPanel>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </h:panelGrid>
</rich:panel>

<rich:panel id="pnlRepContainer">
    <a4j:outputPanel id="rep">
        <rich:panel rendered="#{not empty adminBean.currentItem}"
            header="Add Customer">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <a4j:commandButton value="Add New" />
                <a4j:commandButton value="Delete" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </rich:panel>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
</rich:panel>
```

Comment: I implemented the changes given by you in the above answer . But still it is not working . 

what I found is that ,  #{adminBean.currentItem} setter method is not called on selecting item in second dropdown . Looks like execute="@this" is not working  . 

But in first drop down setter method for #{adminBean.currentType} is called successfully .

Comment: @KshitijJain Make sure your managed bean is at least `@ViewScoped` or wider. Don't have any business logic in your getter/setter methods. It would be better if you edit your question and **add** some of your managed bean code in order to get better help.

Comment: This is the link of my local server for this page :  
http://172.22.36.66:8080/Bank-war/faces/adminhome.xhtml

Please see how it is looking.

Comment: @KshitijJain looks like server is down. Still, it is preferable to help based on info on the question and not providing external links with question parts. Remember that future readers will look into the question and will want to understand both problem and solution.

Comment: You are right. I have resolved the problem by changing the BeanScope to ViewScoped. Previously I was using RequestScoped of CDI bean .

Comment: @KshitijJain if this answer solved your problem (or helped you the most) then please click on the check below the rep to mark it as an answer.